# SQL using while loop until nex row doesn't match condition

Tags: sql, loops

I have a view looking like this below. 
The `Value` describes a condition in the view. All rows are ordered by their date. My plan is to sum up all amounts where the value is 0 until there is a row with the value 1. 
In this case the result should be 20+15=35. Row `#4` need to be ignored because the value 1 in row 3.

```
Row | Value | Amount | Date       |
-----------------------------------  
1   | 0     | 20     | 01.01.2016 |
2   | 0     | 15     | 02.01.2016 |    
3   | 1     | 50     | 03.01.2016 |
4   | 0     | 50     | 04.01.2016 |
5   | 1     | 10     | 05.01.2016 |
```

Has somebody an idea to solve this in SQL?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You certainly don't want a loop, but the optimal solution may vary depending on your database vendor and version. A generic solution would be `SELECT SUM(Value) FROM YourTable WHERE Value = 0 AND Date < (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM YourTable WHERE Value = 1)`

Comment: It is an MS SQL Server 2012
But thank you very much your comment was already the solution! 
So simple i just dont thought about it :D